# How to deal with first and second(?) rendering useEffect and useState?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-hooks, firebase-storage

When I go to FormPage I call this customHook to get a path for the images I may upload in the form survey. But in the very beginning I get 'image/event/NaN' and after some miliseconds it changes to 'image/event/5'

```
import { ref, listAll } from "firebase/storage";
import { FirebaseStorage } from "../firebase/config";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export const useGetLastFolder = (postType) => {

    const [folderPath, setFolderPath] = useState([]);

    const listRef = ref(FirebaseStorage, `image/${postType}`);

    useEffect(() => {
        listAll(listRef)
            .then((res) => {
                const arrayFolders = res.prefixes.map((folderRef) => {
                    return folderRef.name;
                })
                const lastFolder = (parseInt(arrayFolders[arrayFolders.length - 1]) + 1).toString();
                setFolderPath(`image/${postType}/${lastFolder}`);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
            });

    }, [])


    return {
        lastPossibleFolderPath: folderPath
    }

}
```

I tested putting as initialState '[4]' and I get 'image/event/5' and it works perfect.

So the setFolders sets undefined(?) the first render and after that set the array of folders.

Answer (score 0):

In your current code, folders is initialized to `[]`, which had length 0. That means you are trying to access folders[-1] on following line

```
const lastFolder = (parseInt(folders[folders.length - 1]) + 1).toString();
```

Which is undefined and `parseInt` would return `NaN`. You need to handle this case.

```
const lastFolder = (parseInt(folders[folders.length - 1] || 0) + 1).toString();
```

Or whatever default value suits in your case.

Comment: I've changed a bit the code and what my FormPage.jsx gets when calls useGetLastFolder is '[]' and few seconds after it changes to the expected result: 'image/event/5' , but the function imageHandler stays with the first result ( '[]' ), not with 'image/event/5'